# How can I fix HTML elements not showing up because of a js script?

Tags: javascript, html

Loading this causes nothing to show up except for the pink background! When I remove the `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js">` line, everything works again! I need that script for the API to work, so how can I fix the body elements disappearing?

```html
<head>
        <title>My Drive - Google Drive</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylin.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js">
        <script src="app.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>MVTennis vids! :D</h1>
        <button onclick="newVideo()">New Video</button>
        <hr>
        <p> yeet yeet </p>
    </body>
```

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Thank you all for any help! :)

Comment: Close the tags, then check for console errors.

Comment: Yes, close those script tags. Then have a look [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md) to see if you loaded the library correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to close the script tags on each one, like so:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Try that and see if it resolves it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it on only the top line and it did nothing, so I assumed that closing the script would not help. Much appreciated!

Comment: @JPo8192 Welcome, and as a reminder, linked stylesheets do NOT need a closing tag.

For example: <link rel="stylesheet" href="example-css.css"> if you plan to add CSS to the site as well.